# convert data frame to rdd and join

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to compare join performance between dataframe and RDD so I tried to convert dataframe to rdd and then apply join which is failing due to below error.

Error:-
console:34: error: not found: value pairRDD1
              pairRDD1.join(pairRDD2)

Am I missing something here ?

```
val df1=sqlContext.sql("select column1,column2,column3,column4 from table_1 AS a")

df1.printSchema()

val pairRdd1=df1.rdd.map(r => (r.getString(0),r.getString(1),r.getString(2),r.getString(3))).map { case (column1,column2,column3,column4) => ((column1),column2,column3,column4)}

val df2=sqlContext.sql("select column1,column2,column3,column4 from table_2 AS b")   

df2.printSchema()

val pairRdd2=df2.rdd.map(r => ((r.getString(0)),r.getString(1),r.getString(2),r.getString(3))).map {case (column1,column2,column3,column4) => ((column1),column2,column3,column4)}

val joined = pairRDD1.join(pairRDD2)



console:34: error: not found: value pairRDD1
pairRDD1.join(pairRDD2)
```

Thanks

Comment: It's `pairRdd1` not `pairRDD1` same for `pairRdd2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says everything `console:34: error: not found: value pairRDD1 pairRDD1.join(pairRDD2)`

Compiler could not find `pairRDD1` because you dont have you just have `pairRdd1`

You have `val joined = pairRDD1.join(pairRDD2)`

which should be

```
val joined = pairRdd1.join(pairRdd2)
```

You can create `RDD[String, (String, String...)]` by

```
  val pairRdd1=df1.rdd.map(r => (r.getString(0),(r.getString(1),r.getString(2),r.getString(3))))

  val pairRdd2=df2.rdd.map(r => (r.getString(0),(r.getString(1),r.getString(2),r.getString(3))))
```

Comment: yes you are right my typo sucks , but now I am getting different error

Comment: error: value join is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String, String)]

Comment: got the answer need to make the rdd as a pair

Comment: val pairRdd2=df2.rdd.map(r => ((r.getString(0)),r.getString(1),r.getString(2),r.getString(3))).map {case (column1,column2,column3,column4) => ((column1),(column2,column3,column4)}

Comment: @sriharikalicharanTummala ` val pairRdd2=df2.rdd.map(r => (r.getString(0),(r.getString(1),r.getString(2),r.getString(3))))
`this is enough